# Beginner question about SCSS here in this Codesandbox

Tags: reactjs, sass

I have this React Javascript [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-file-viewer-master-mzijq?file=/src/components/file-viewer.jsx) that usese SCSS.

I wonder if you look at this file [docx-viewer.jsx](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-file-viewer-master-mzijq?file=/src/components/drivers/docx-viewer.jsx) you see it's loading the docx.scss like this;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import mammoth from 'mammoth/mammoth.browser';

import '../../styles/docx.scss';
import Loading from '../loading';

export default class extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const jsonFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    jsonFile.open('GET', this.props.filePath, true);
    jsonFile.send();
    jsonFile.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    jsonFile.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (jsonFile.readyState === 4 && jsonFile.status === 200) {
        mammoth.convertToHtml(
          { arrayBuffer: jsonFile.response },
          { includeDefaultStyleMap: true },
        )
        .then((result) => {
          const docEl = document.createElement('div');
          docEl.className = 'document-container';
          docEl.innerHTML = result.value;
          document.getElementById('docx').innerHTML = docEl.outerHTML;
        })
        .catch((a) => {
          console.log('alexei: something went wrong', a);
        })
        .done();
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="docx">
        <Loading />
      </div>);
  }
}
```

The docx.scss SCSS is starting with the `.pg-viewer-wrapper {..`  and looking in the code there is no use of the `.pg-viewer-wrapper {..` , the component is not using `.pg-viewer-wrapper {..` .

The docx.scss;

```
.pg-viewer-wrapper {
  overflow-y: scroll;

  #docx {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .document-container {
    padding: 30px;
    width: 700px;
    background: white;
    margin: auto;
  }

  html,
  bodyaddress,
  blockquote,
  body,
  dd,
  div,
  dl,
  dt,
  fieldset,
  form,
  frame,
  frameset,
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5,
  h6,
  noframes,
  ol,
  p,
  ul,
  center,
  dir,
  hr,
  menu,
  pre {
    display: block;
    unicode-bidi: embed;
  }
  li {
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: disc;
  }
  head {
    display: none
  }
  table {
    display: table
  }
  img {
    width: 100%
  }
  tr {
    display: table-row
  }
  thead {
    display: table-header-group
  }
  tbody {
    display: table-row-group
  }
  tfoot {
    display: table-footer-group
  }
  col {
    display: table-column
  }
  colgroup {
    display: table-column-group
  }
  th {
    display: table-cell
  }
  td {
    display: table-cell;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  }
  caption {
    display: table-caption
  }
  th {
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
  }
  caption {
    text-align: center
  }
  body {
    margin: 8px
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: .67em 0;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: .75em 0;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 1.17em;
    margin: .83em 0;
  }
  h4,
  p,
  blockquote,
  ul,
  fieldset,
  form,
  ol,
  dl,
  dir,
  menu {
    margin: 1.12em 0
  }
  h5 {
    font-size: .83em;
    margin: 1.5em 0;
  }
  h6 {
    font-size: .75em;
    margin: 1.67em 0;
  }
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5,
  h6,
  b,
  strong {
    font-weight: bolder
  }
  blockquote {
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
  }
  i,
  cite,
  em,
  var,
  address {
    font-style: italic
  }
  pre,
  tt,
  code,
  kbd,
  samp {
    font-family: monospace
  }
  pre {
    white-space: pre
  }
  button,
  textarea,
  input,
  select {
    display: inline-block
  }
  big {
    font-size: 1.17em
  }
  small,
  sub,
  sup {
    font-size: .83em
  }
  sub {
    vertical-align: sub
  }
  sup {
    vertical-align: super
  }
  table {
    border-spacing: 2px
  }
  thead,
  tbody,
  tfoot {
    vertical-align: middle
  }
  td,
  th,
  tr {
    vertical-align: inherit
  }
  s,
  strike,
  del {
    text-decoration: line-through
  }
  hr {
    border: 1px inset
  }
  ol,
  ul,
  dir,
  menu,
  dd {
    margin-left: 40px
  }
  ol {
    list-style-type: decimal
  }
  ol ul, ol ul,
  ul ol, ul ol,
  ul ul, ul ul,
  ol ol, ol ol {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  u,
  ins {
    text-decoration: underline
  }
  br:before {
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre-line;
  }
  center {
    text-align: center
  }
  :link,
  :visited {
    text-decoration: underline
  }
  :focus {
    outline: thin dotted invert
  }
  /* Begin bidirectionality settings (do not change) */
  BDO[DIR="ltr"] {
    direction: ltr;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  }
  BDO[DIR="rtl"] {
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  }
  *[DIR="ltr"] {
    direction: ltr;
    unicode-bidi: embed;
  }
  *[DIR="rtl"] {
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: embed;
  }
  @media print {
    h1 {
      page-break-before: always
    }
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6 {
      page-break-after: avoid
    }
    ul,
    ol,
    dl {
      page-break-before: avoid
    }
  }
}
```

But when I change the docx.scss then I see that changes in the component. So how does SCSS work I thought one must explicitly in the render like do  `className="pg-viewer-wrapper"` adding the CSS selector and then everything under the `pg-viewer-wrapper` selector can be used

Comment: Because the component is wrapped in [FileViewer](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-file-viewer-master-mzijq?file=/src/components/file-viewer.jsx) (which uses the class) when rendered.

Comment: @Martin Thanks hmm, so I could move all docx.scss code into  FileViewer main.scss.  ok I see. Must ask is this good coding?

Comment: I would try to always have corresponding component files and style files, without any mixup between them; because it keeps the cognitive load reasonably low. I don't know if you can use it in your project, but in my personal opinion the clearest and cleanest way to style react components is via css-modules. And a word about the folder structure: I abandoned having a `styles` folder long ago and now keep the component files and the scss files together. So a `src/components/kerfuffle` folder will contain `Kerfuffle.js` and `kerfuffle.scss` (or `kerfuffle.module.scss`)

Comment: @Martin Thanks. What is confusing is that both file-viewer.jsx and docx-viewer.jsx both have scss files and in both there is .pg-viewer-wrapper - I was thinking that docx-viewer.jsx could not use the .pg-viewer-wrapper. I think then now that this type of coding must be bad?????

Comment: You seem to assume that there is some kind of boundary during runtime regarding different components and the style files each of them imported. Well, that is not the case. CSS is global. There are several approaches to somehow rein in this side of CSS. One good approach is BEM, another is css-modules. If you ask me: first choice is css-modules. If that is not possible because of some specific project requirements my second best choice would be BEM. If that is also not allowed for some reason I usually resort to violence. But you must decide what floats your boat.

Comment: @Martin Violence HAhAHh (Happy New Year btw). Can you post an Answer something like.. Because the component is wrapped in FileViewer.. so I can approve it, closing this Q